# telegram inline bot - InlineQueryResultCachedPhoto does not show title and description

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm using **telegram bot api** for implementing an inline bot. For sending query result to the user, I'm using [`answerInlineQuery`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answerinlinequery) method in this way. This is just an example for showing a photo that exist on telegram server to user:

```
$results = array(
    array(
        "type" => "photo",
        "id" => "1",
        "photo_file_id" => the file id,
        "title" => "test title",
        "description" => "test description",
        "caption" => "test caption",
        "parse_mode" => "HTML"
    ),
);

$postFields["results"] = json_encode($results);
$postFields["cache_time"] = 0;

//send $postFields to telegram bot api server with curl
```

This works and after user sending inline query, one image shows as the result list. But the problem is **two fields `title` and `description` does not show in the result list, even these are exist in telegram api documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultcachedphoto)**.

What's is the problem and whay these two fields does not present in the result list?

Answer (score 0):

Title and description for photos would be shown only in situations when preview of the image can't be generated.

https://t.me/BotTalk/713870

But if you use `InlineQueryResultPhoto` instead `InlineQueryResultCachedPhoto` and pass `thumb_url`, telegram will be display title and description, BUT only in the list result.

To display queries as list, you need to add `InlineQueryResultArticle` in your response.

[image]